# Having problems accessing a function from another JS file

Tags: javascript, dom

I am having troubles accessing a function of a js file from another file.

I have created a new file named "test.js" in the same path as main.js file.

In test.js I have only a function:

```
function HelloWorld(){
   console.log("hi user");
}
```

And now I want to call this function in the main.js.
In the main.js I have the code where I append a script tag of the test.js.

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'module';
script.src = './test.js';    
document.head.appendChild(script);
console.log("head=",head.document)
HelloWorld();
```

Here in the browser's console I can see that the script tag is added successfully there.

But when I want to call the test.js function HelloWorld(); it throws an expection saying `"HelloWorld" is not defined`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It should be `function`.

Comment: @Unmitigated I misspelled it here. In my code is `function`.

Comment: "But when I want to call the test.js function" — When you do what? You aren't doing that in the code you've shared! Please provide a [mcve]. (I guess you're calling it before the other script has been executed so it doesn't exist yet).

Comment: Why are you using `createElement` to load a module instead of `import`?

Comment: @Quentin I call it after the console.log. Check my updated question.

Comment: When I use `import` it gives me the error `'import' and may only appear at the top level`. I didn't knew how ti fix it out and thought of this solution as the "easiest"...

Comment: @LeotrimR — I think you cut off the end of that error message. I would expect it to say "...level of a module". You need to make the script a module… like you are with the script element you are generating dynamically in your original code. `<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

1. The current script hasn't finished running so the other script can't have run so can't have created the function in time
2. The other script is being loaded as a module, so the function it creates won't be in the global scope anyway

Use modules properly instead of trying to fake them using DOM and globals.

```
function HelloWorld(){
    console.log("hi user");
}

export default HelloWorld;
```

and

```
import HelloWorld from './test.js';
HelloWorld();
```